# story about star travel where the creatures on board evolve during the voyage

Tags: story-identification, space, evolution

Need the name/author. I don't remember much, I'm afraid. Just fragments. I do remember reading the story assuming that the creatures on board were human, only to find out towards the end that they were rodents(?)

I think the original intelligent builders of the ship (a hollowed-out comet?) were human (but maybe not), and that you find out that these builders were no longer on board. They may have all died out over the huge amounts of time involved in the travel?

Anyway the rodents (rats?) began to fill the void that is left, getting smarter, developing a society. They consider the original inhabitants to be gods. They finally arrive at their destination. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

There is one great mutated-rats-on-a-spaceship story. If this isn't the one you were looking for, it should be: ["Giant Killer"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45646) by [A. Bertram Chandler](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?72), first published in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, October 1945](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57643+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v36n02_1945-10_c2c#page/n7/mode/2up). It's told from the viewpoint of the rats, but you don't find out that they're rats till the end of the story, which is now completely spoiled:

> Shrick clung to the dead man's neck, looked long and longingly at the glittering instruments, the shining switches and levers, whose purpose he would never understand, whose inertia would have defeated any attempt of his fast ebbing strength to move them. He looked at the flaming doom ahead, and knew that this was what had been foretold.
>
> Had the metaphor existed in his language, he would have told himself that he and the few surviving People were caught like rats in a trap.
>
> But even the Giants would not have used that phrase in its metaphorical sense.
>
> For that is all that the People were—rats in a trap.

Chandler was a sea captain, and this story was inspired by his experiences with real rats on seagoing vessels.