# Looking for a short story with a twist in the tale about a society under attack and it turns out they were rats living in a basement

Tags: story-identification

I read this many years ago in an anthology I've lost and can't remember the name of. There are two groups of creatures separated by a lake and they are at war - you assume you are on an alien planet, but it turns out you're not. The creatures are attacked by a giant and join together to fight it. One smart creature decides there is more to the universe and climbs a hill towards the sun. He survives. They are actually rats in the basement of a disused building, the giant was a small boy, and they are wiped out by an exterminator. Anyone remember this?

Comment: Hmm. I don't know about the lake, but how about Avram Davidson's 1962 story, ["The Tail-tied Kings"](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56782), where it only slowly dawns on the reader that it is about rats and humans' attempt to exterminate them? Follow the link and check out the covers to see if any look right.

Comment: As @InvisibleTrihedron mentioned, it could be *The Tail-tied Kings".  You can read it online at https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v20n04_1962-04/page/n25/mode/2up

Comment: That's not it, but it looks interesting!

Comment: Not "The men in the walls" by William Tenn https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31307718-the-men-in-the-walls

Comment: Is "many years ago" more like 10 or 60? It might help a lot if you could narrow it down to a decade or two.

Comment: And it's not ["Giant Killer"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117854/story-about-star-travel-where-the-creatures-on-board-evolve-during-the-voyage/117856#117856) which is set on a spaceship.

Answer (score 3):

*[Giant Killer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_Killer_(story))*, by A. Bertram Chandler. First published in *Astounding Science Fiction*, October 1945.

The big twist in the story is that, at the very end, the "People" are revealed to be rats. They are in a spaceship, not the basement of a house, but there are "Giants" which turn out to be the human crew.

From Wikipedia:

> "Giant Killer" is told from the point-of-view of a colony of mutants living in a spaceship. Though they are eventually (in the final sentence) revealed to be rats, they are obviously sentient lifeforms: they have a culture, complete with marriage, seers, governmental structures, specialized safety equipment, and ritualized combat. They are illiterate, albeit: they marvel as the giants make black marks on "skin," which they perceive as some inscrutable form of "sorcery." The "giants" of the story's title are the humans crewing the spaceship. Much is made of the mutants' efforts to understand the giants' fascinating world, including such locales as the Place-of-Life-Which-Is-Not-Life, obviously the robotics laboratory.

The People (that is, the rats, but that twist hasn't been revealed yet) attack some giants, including the Little Giant (who is presumably a young human boy). Quoting now from the story:

> Shrick's keen ears could distinguish the breathing of three different sleepers. The Thin-One was there, his respiration, like himself, had a meager quality. Loud-Voice was loud even in sleep. And Bare-Head, the chief of the Giants, breathed with a quiet authority.
>
> And the Little Giant who, alone of all his people, was alert and awake was in the Place-of-Little-Lights.
>
> Shrick knew that it was now or never. Any attempt to deal with the Giants singly must surely bring the great, hot light foretold by Three-Eyes. Now, with any luck at all, he could deal with the three sleepers and then lie in wait for the Little Giant.
>
> ...
>
> It was not until the Thin-One, who must have been in the throes of a bad dream, murmured and stirred in his sleep that Shrick came out of his doorway. The keen blade with which he had slain Fat-Belly was grasped in both his hands. He launched himself toward the uneasy sleeper. His weapon sliced down once only—how often had he rehearsed this in his imagination!—and for the Thin-One the dream was over.

Shrick kills several giants, but the Little Giant escapes. Shrick crawls after him, but in the end, Shrick and all the People are doomed. The final sentence reveals that the People are rats.

> He looked at the flaming doom ahead, and knew that this was what had been foretold. Had the metaphor existed in his language, he would have told himself that he and the few surviving People were caught like rats in a trap. But even the Giants would not have used that phrase in its metaphorical sense. For that is all that the People were—rats in a trap.

[image: Cover art for Astounding Science Fiction, October 1945]

Comment: I thought about this too, but this sentence in the question has no overlap with this story:"They are actually rats in the basement of a disused building, the giant was a small boy, and they are wiped out by an exterminator. "

Comment: "Giant Killer" matches nothing in the question, except "at the end you find out they are rats".

Comment: The more I think about it, you're probably right. I don't think "Giant Killer" is the right story. It's got some of the elements--a society of People who turn out to be rats, Giants who turn out to be humans, a little Giant who might be a child, the rats killing the Giants, and the People/rats die at the end. But the setting--a spaceship instead of the basement of a building--is a pretty major difference. And "Giant Killer" contains no exterminator, and I don't think there's a lake or two warring factions of rats. So, not likely the right answer.